# Sink drain too far from the wall

Tags: plumbing, drain, sink

My drain is too far away from the wall. I cannot fit the cabinet.

While I recognize I can push it horizontal arm it is not good enough which means I have to cut pipe which is in the wall.

Can I just cut wall tube and use some kind of adapter?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. You should [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you know how to participate on the site with upvotes for helpful information and checks for accepted answers. It would help to have a few more pics and some more info. Is the problem that the cabinet won't fit or are you only asking how to connect into the drain line. The drain doesn't appear to be a normal stub. Is a P trap already installed?

Comment: Hey, that P-trap still has horizontal adjustment left. If you loosen the slip-joint nut there at the wall pipe, you can slide the whole trap another inch (at least) toward the wall. You should be using a rubber slip-joint washer there, not plastic.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Educate me! How can you tell that it has adjustment room left?

Comment: Because there's still some straight length before the bend begins.  Not a huge amount, but it depends how much leeway you need before you have to do something that requires actual work.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your asking about how to tie your sink drain to the wall stub. Standard 1 1/2" PVC drain pipe has slp compression fittings that give you a lot of flexibility in setting up your P trap and drain. In most cases you can make adjustments without shortening the wall stub.
However, in some cases you may have to shorten the wall stub. If you absolutely have to shorten it you can do so by cutting it on the wall side of the connector in the picture. Don't trim off any more than you absolutely have to. Do a square cut and debur the end. You can then buy a new connector and attach it with PVC adhesive. Follow all directions regarding priming, etc.
Here is a guide on setting up a proper P trap:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have what is called an **adjustable P-trap**. The horizontal leg that runs into the slip-joint fitting at the wall pipe can be moved in and out of the wall pipe. You simply loosen the slip-joint nut in your picture and slide the trap arm further in to make the whole trap assembly move closer to the wall:

[image]

It looks to me like you have at least another inch of horizontal movement toward the wall available to you.

**NOTES**:

- that horizontal arm arm comes 10" - 12" long from the factory. If it hasn't already been cut down,there is a chance it will strike a fitting (elbow or tee) deep inside the wall pipe, preventing the additional horizontal adjustment you need. If this happens, simply disassemble and cut the trap arm shorter.
- Because the slip-joint washer (under the slip-joint nut) may now land on the stamps molded into the plastic trap arm, I recommend that a *rubber* slip-joint washer be used there, rather than a plastic one.
- you want to avoid adjusting so far that the slip-joint lands on the curved part of the trap bend.
- if you must, you can cut the wall pipe back and glue on a threaded adapter to which your trap will connect, just as it does so now. Please avoid cutting back too far and leaving just a stub...

Comment: You're saying that the horizontal arm can be moved in to the slip joint nut until you start to hit the curve of the elbow?

Comment: Good answer but- While i agree that there is room in the slip joint, and the pipe probably needs to be shortened, we do not know if the Ptrap can swing enough to allow more of pipe to push into the slip joint. "*My drain is too far away from the wall*"  is vague, i am not convinced that this is the problem the OP is trying to solve, i can not quite discern what they are trying to say. That said i think your answer is correct.

Comment: @Alaska Man, yes the phrasing in the question isn't exactly clear but I chalk that up to unfamiliarity with plumbing terms. The last sentence- "Can I just cut the tube and use some kind of adapter?" along with the picture makes me think his sink tailpiece is closer to the wall than the current trap set-up will accomodate...

Comment: @Freeman, yes... by design.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to confirm that.

Comment: Dears. Thanks for your help. While there is some space with pushing in horizontal arm it is not enough to fit my drawers - meaning I have to indeed cut wall pipe back and glue the adapter. I will search for adapter in home depot.